# Flutter flexible alert dialog list

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a dialog which has a scrollable list in it.

My issues are

1. When too few items the dialog doesn't shrink to fit.
2. When the list is too large the buttons are overflown.
3. The list somehow doesn't scroll freely and keep moving to its initial position.

Code:

```
  show(){
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
            elevation: constants.dElevation,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(constants.dRadius),
            ),
            title: Text("title"),
            content: getAllSelectedShipments());
      },
    );
  }

  Widget getAllSelectedShipments() {

    return Container(
        width: 300.0, // Change as per your requirement
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            UtilUI.getColorScaffold(
              constants,
              constants.transparent,
              ListView.separated(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                    title: Text("title $index"),
                    subtitle: Text("subtitle $index"),,
                    onTap: () async {},
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Divider();
                },
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                UtilUI.getButtonSmall(context, constants, Icons.cancel,
                    constants.sCancel, (constants) => null),
                UtilUI.getButtonSmall(context, constants, Icons.check,
                    constants.sDone, (constants) => null),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```

**When too few items**

[image]

**When too many items**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these !

add `mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,` to `Column` widget

and wrap `ListView` with `Flexible`

and wrap `Row` children with `Expanded`

Answer (score 0):

**Use `Center` and give width and height to `double.infinity` then give margin to your need. Use `Expanded` on `list-view` to give it max height.**

By doing that center will take all height and width given by your container. Then you don't have to worry about pixels overflowing.

```
 Widget getAllSelectedShipments() {
    return Center(
        child: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 50, 20, 50),
          child: Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.separated(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: 10,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              leading: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                              title: Text("title $index"),
                              subtitle: Text("subtitle $index"),
                              onTap: () async {},
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Divider();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.cancel),
                          Icon(Icons.check),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ))),
        ));
  }
```

Don't use content in `AlertDialog` instead use `Scaffold` to give customized view.

```
 showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return getAllSelectedShipments();
                },
              );
```